# IIS7 Remote sever - Ip Address issue

Tags: iis-7

i have  a local iis web site ( name  is abc) , when accessing  this  web site  from 2nd pc  like    **192.168.1.666/abc** but  i want  replace ip address with name  like  **Csc/abc**
 help me

Answer (score 1):

ON second PC you need to add string in the file "C\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" like this:

192.168.1.666      Csc

Comment: Usually you will also need to restart your browser (especially with IE).